# access shared icloud photo stream without idevice or mac

Tags: mac, icloud

problem: My wife was shared a photo stream from her boss at work. We don't own any idevices or mac products to create said icloud account.

question 1: Is there a way to virtualize a mac? My plan would be to virtualize osx and setup and icloud account on the vm

question 2: Can said mac pull the shared icloud data and publish it elsewhere?(ie dropbox, box.net etc etc) so that my wife can view the photostream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. But you do require a valid OS X license.
2. Yes. But it involves some work.
3. The most inexpensive solution is just to ask someone with an Apple device (e.g. her boss) to create an account from their devices, and then just delete the info from their devices. Then go to https://www.icloud.com/ connect, change your password, and ask her boss to share the PhotoStream with her account.

Additional info: Since iCloud, it seems you can't view any shared photo stream on the browser. You will have to install iCloud for Windows, and find the Photos in your account's Pictures directory. More info at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486.

Comment: 1. I'm sure I can find one. How can it be done? Virtual Box? VMware server? 2. How much work? details plz.

Comment: on second thought, i'll just try 3, since its easiest and work my way back if that doesnt work

Comment: 1. Whatever virtualization platform you want, I guess VBox is the most inexpensive. 2. You need an dropbox account, you need a script to copy the pics from inside the somewhat chaotic iPhoto library to a folder on her boss's computer which needs to be synced to your dropbox account, etc... 3. Good choice :)